# unpacking a dictionary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, iterable-unpacking

I have a dictionary as follows

```
    dict = {'Sept close adds': close_adds, 'Sept close deletes': close_deletes, 'Sept Changes': annual_changes, 'June Changes': june_changes}
```

i want to remove the key and value 'June Changes': june_changes from the above dictionary and have the value (june_changes) as a separate variable to use later on in the code.

I have tried to use the below code but it does not create a new variable with the value i want while maintaining the dictionary excluding june_changes.

```
keys, values = dict.keys(), dict.values()
```

can someone please help me?

Comment: Please revisit your tutorial on accessing dict values.  Your one line of coding attempt seems to be drawn from an iteration example, rather than from how to obtain and then delete a single item.  Each of these is a simple browser search.

Comment: You're also using a reserved word (`dict`) as a variable name, which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.pop` does what you want

```
>>> d = {"foo":1, "bar":2}
>>> bar = d.pop("bar")
>>> d
{'foo': 1}
>>> bar
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not affect the dictionary in any way. Assuming you have the key in a variable `key`, you can do:

```py
value = dict[key]
del dict[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use**

With dictionary d (changed from 'dict' since not good to call name a dictionary dict since conflicts with a builtin function)

```
d = {'Sept close adds': close_adds, 'Sept close deletes': close_deletes, 'Sept Changes': annual_changes, 'June Changes': june_changes}

# get value
june_changes = d['June Changes']

# delete key
del d ['June Changes']

# Show new dictionary
import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
```

*Updated dictionary d*

```
{'Sept Changes': 'annual_changes',
 'Sept close adds': 'close_adds',
 'Sept close deletes': 'close_deletes'}
```